# "Progress() is not defined" with onClick -- but it is defined

Tags: javascript

I have a simple page with a file selection button and a submit button to complete the upload.  On click of the submit button, I call a JavaScript function to display different text in the "text_display" class shown below ("In Process . . . ).

There are two ways to call this JavaScript function.  I can call it using an onClick command in the code for the submit button or I can include a "form" wrapper and call it from an onSubmit command.

Either way, I get a message that says the function Progress() is not defined.   But it is defined, see below.

Here is the code.  To use the form wrapper, delete the comment symbols and remove the "onClick" from the submit button code.

```
<div class="header_upload"><b>File Selection</b></div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 13%;">

<!--<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="Progress()">-->

<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Select file to upload</button>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
</div><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 5%;">
<button class="btn" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"    onClick="Progress()">Upload</button></div>

</div>
<!--</form>-->

<br><br><br><br>

<div id="td1" class="text_display">*&nbsp;&nbsp;In process . . . </div>

<script>
function Progress() {

document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    id = "#td" + i.toString();
    console.log("Node count:", a.childNodes.length, "and the current time is:", Date.now());
    console.log(id);
    setTimeout(function(id));
    }
}
</script>

<script>
setTimeout(function(id){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "new content";
}, 500);
</script>
```

Here is the css:

```
.header_upload{
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: rgb(175,222,162);
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(117,163,126);
  color: green;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 8px 20px;
      border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  color: rgb(117,163,126);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

button img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

* html button { width: 90px; }

.upload_text{
   font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16pt;
   color: rgb(175,222,162);
}

.text_display{
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: rgb(73,115,186);
    margin-left: 18%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#td1.text_display{ }
#td2.text_display{ }
#td3.text_display{ }
#td4.text_display{ }
#td5.text_display{ }
#td6.text_display{ }
#td7.text_display{ }

.text_display_f{ 
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: rgb(73,115,186);
    margin-left: 15%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color:rgb(175,222,162);
    font-size: 16pt;
    margin-left: 16%;
}

input.alignright {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

My research on this issue suggests that I would add addEventListener, which I did, but it doesn't change the result.  No other research has changed my result.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: `“JSFunction() is not defined” ... but it is defined` where? there is no `JSFunction` in your code

Comment: Setting up an event handler inside another event handler is generally a sign that something's wrong, especially when you're setting up a handler for the same event.

Comment: I edited the title.  In the text I specify the name of the function, but I used a generic reference in the title.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(id);` clearly a syntax error, therefore the Progress function will not exist... please check your developer tools console for other errors

Comment: As @Bravo says, this appears to be a syntax error, which will cause the `Progress` function to not actually be defined - does the console not show this? (Also there are other issues in your code, see @Pointy's comment.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond - there's more than one syntax error :p

Comment: I changed the error on setTimeout(function(id); but I still have the same error message.  The console does not show any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question.  In the script above, these two lines are incorrect:

```
console.log("Node count:", a.childNodes.length, "and the current time is:", Date.now());

setTimeout(function(id));
```

When I remove those two lines, the script executes correctly:

```
<script>
function Progress() {

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    id = "#td" + i.toString();
    console.log(id);
    }
}
</script>
```